# what should be the correct Algorithm to Get Array B from Array A

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Array A= [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]];
And the result will be B B=[1,0,4,3,2,1,0,2,1];
the elements of A is given and the result will be B.
Elements in A can only be 0 and 1. 
we need to count backward from the last element in A, if there are consecutive 1's then the element in A and B will be 1 but for the 2nd consecutive 1 in A it will be 2 in be and for the 3rd one in A the element will be 3 in B
but for 0 it will be 0. I have tried the following way but I am not getting the output.

```
<script>

var A= [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]];
var B =[];
//var B= A.length;

var lastValueOne;
var consecutiveOnes = 0;

for (i = A.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ( lastValueOne== false) 
        {
                consecutiveOnes = 0; 
                B[i] = 0;
        }
        else 
        { 
            consecutiveOnes++; 
            B[i] = consecutiveOnes; 
        }

        if (A[i] == 1) 
        { 
            lastValueOne = true; 
        }

        else 
        { 
            lastValueOne = false; 
        }
    }

  //console.log(B[i]);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = B;
```

Comment: And what is the problem? What went wrong with your solution?

Comment: I am not getting the output.

Comment: Which output do you get instead?

Comment: I am getting 1 0 as the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the given array and map the value of the count if a truthy value is given at the actual index. Then iterate until a falsy value is found and return the count.

```js
var array = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    result = array.map(function (_, i, a) { // take only index and array as parameter
        var count = 0;                      // declare and initialize counter with zero
        while(a[i++]) {                     // check value at actual index and inc index
            count++;                        // increment counter while true/truthy
        }
        return count;                       // return count
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Moving the idea of [le_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647737/le-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834859/1447675) a bit ahead without using a `sum` variable and using the first element of the result array `r[0]` for keeping the cumulative sum.

```js
var array = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    result = array.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
        return [a && (r[0] || 0) + a].concat(r);
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much , Just one request, can you please just elaborate a little bit on function(_,i , a)  @ninaScholz

Comment: if you mean the first approach, it uses a loop to look at the next element and dexide if to add or to leave the count loop. the second iterates from the right side and uses the value of the last element for addign the actual value.

Comment: Yes I meant the first one, I think that one is easy to understand. I can understand the while loop and count but still confused about the backward adding , is it the function?

Comment: the function is a callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is called for every element of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answers are very clear, so do you think the 1st approach is better of the 2nd one? for me the 1st is easier to understand

Comment: the second needs only one iteration, the first one for the array and some sub iterations for the elements to count.

Comment: How can I do the same thing in Java

Comment: @MD.FazlaRabby, actually i can not help with java.

Answer (score 1):

The more descriptive [Array.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight?v=example) lends itself well to your task of computing cumulative sums from right to left.

```js
// Return cumulative sums from right, reset on zero:
function cumSumRight(array, sum = 0) {
  return array.reduceRight((result, a) => {
    sum = a > 0 ? sum + a : 0;
    result.unshift(sum);
    return result;
  }, []);
}

// Example:
console.log(cumSumRight([1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1])); // [1,0,4,3,2,1,0,2,1]
```

To fix your current solution, write `A.length` instead of `A.Length`. You can then simplify to:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  sum += A[i];
  if (A[i] === 0) {
    sum = 0; 
  }
  B.unshift(sum);
}
```

Comment: you could omit `sum` by using `result[0]`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, but is saving a single `Number` allocation really worth it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should only increment `consecutiveOnes` if last value was 1 AND the current value is also 1.
But the logic can be simplier, because when the last value is false, your consecutive value should also be 0.

```
var A= [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1];
var B = [];
var consecutiveOnes = 0;

for (i = A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (A[i] == 1) 
        {
            consecutiveOnes += 1;
        }
        else 
        { 
            consecutiveOnes = 0; 
        }
        B[i] = consecutiveOnes;
    }

console.log(B);
```